# Setting a default element in SOAPUI

Tags: api, wsdl, soapui

I've been using SOAPUI a lot lately and noticed that there are some elements I want to set for all request, such as an API key, or a date range.

Is there a way to automatically do this?

example: Every request begins with:
    
      
         ?

Is there a way to automatically fill in the api key for every request?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is No.

But you can try playing with defining properties. You can set properties at project level and then use the property everywhere you need. 
It is not automated - you have to use the property correctly everywhere you need it.

Answer (score 0):

In the project tree on the left you see all your WSDLs and its operations. Right click on an operation and choose **New request**.

Open the new request and set the default properties you want. Now you have two possibilities.

#### Add to TestCase

Right click on the request and choose that option. Then you can choose the TestCase to which you want to add the request.

#### Copy to TestRequests

Right click on the request and choose that option. Now you can choose existing TestRequests to which you want to add the values of the given request. I haven't used that option till now. You have to try if it works as expected.